# Trying to build regex for /"<xsshere>

Tags: regex

I want to build a regex to match below strings.

```js
<xsshere>
'xsshere
"xsshere
\'xsshere
/"xsshere
<XSSHERE>
```

So far I have tried to build below regex

**`(?i)('|"|)(xsshere|<xsshere>)`**

But unfortunately it's not matching below strings.

```js
\'xsshere
/"xsshere
```

Comment: (?:\/?"|\\?')  Can you explain this in more detail??

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not matching a `\` or `/` which are optional and can be in a character class to match either one of them.

The `'` and `"` are not optional but can also be in a character class.

```
(?i)[\\/]?['"]xsshere|<xsshere>
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for a case insensitive match
- `[\\/]?` Optionally (using the question mark) match either \ or / using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `['"]` Match either " or '
  `xsshere` Match literally
- `|` Or
- `<xsshere>` Match literally

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gIYUjZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
(?i)(?:\/?"|\\?')xsshere|<xsshere>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GOUQHE/3).

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive matching
- `(?:\/?"|\\?')` - an optional `/` and then `"` or an optional `\` char and then a `'` char
- `xsshere` - a `xsshere` string
- `|` - or
- `<xsshere>` - an `<xsshere>` string.